# How do I retrieve a user id from mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

This might be a silly question but whats the best practise for getting a userid. I have created an mvc app using the membership provider and have it all wired up and working.
I have a number of controllers that require the userID to perform crud actions and need to be able to use it.

Do I store it in a cookie or is there a better way of doing it?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have to worry about messing around with cookies or anything like that--Membership should take care of all that for you.  All you need to do is check if the user is authenticated, and if so pull out the username

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
```

and

```
var userName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
```

Comment: What about scenarios where 2 users have the same userName?

Answer (score 1):

```
HttpContext.User.Identity.Name
```